# Using Entry Widget in Tkinter with Button returns no attribute despite being defined as String Var - Using Classes/OOP

Tags: python, class, tkinter

trying to learn tkinter and classes with python. I am making a simple word problem generator but cannot understand why I am receiving the same error. I have tried finding resources online to help understand the problem, but most do not involve classes or are woefully brief. I have tried quite a few options to fix, including checking indentation, spelling, changing variable types, etc, but nothing seems to help.Usually this means I am not understanding something fundamental.

When I click on my 'create document' button, which should be bound to the function that passes .get(), I get the following error code:
Error code returned is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\riley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\riley\Documents\Pyth\Test.py", line 174, in get_inputs
    minadd = self.e_add_minvar.get()
AttributeError: 'BigWindow' object has no attribute 'e_add_minvar'
```

Code here:

```
rad_font = ('Cambria', 20)


class BigWindow:


    def __init__(self, root, title, geometry):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title(title)
        self.root.geometry(geometry)

        #labels for columns
        operator_label = Label(self.root, text = 'Choose options', font = ('cambria', 20, 'bold'))
        operator_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        #create check buttons
        addbutt = IntVar()
        subbutt = IntVar()
        multbutt = IntVar()
        divbutt = IntVar()

        Check1 = Checkbutton(self.root, text = 'Addition', variable = addbutt, onvalue = 1, offvalue =0, font = rad_font, pady = 40)
        Check1.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = 'W')
        Check2 = Checkbutton(self.root, text = 'Subtraction', variable = subbutt, onvalue = 1, offvalue =0, font = rad_font, pady = 40)
        Check2.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = 'W')
        Check3 = Checkbutton(self.root, text='Multiplication', variable=multbutt, onvalue = 1, offvalue =0, font = rad_font, pady = 40)
        Check3.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky = 'W')
        Check4 = Checkbutton(self.root, text='Division', variable=divbutt, onvalue=1, offvalue = 0, font = rad_font, pady = 40)
        Check4.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky = 'W')

        #entry widgets for min max
        e_add_minvar = StringVar()
        e_add_minvar.set('32')
        e_add_min = Entry(self.root, bd = 4, relief = 'sunken', textvariable = e_add_minvar, 
        selectborderwidth = 5, font = ('Calibri', 20), width = 8)
        e_add_min.grid(column = 1, row = 1, padx = 40)

        #create/submit button
        create_button = Button(self.root, text = 'Create Document', command = self.get_inputs)
        create_button.grid(row = 3, column = 4)

        self.root.mainloop()
        #function to get all inputs to connect to submit/create button
    def get_inputs(self):
        minadd = self.e_add_minvar.get()
        print(minadd)

class Main:

    proot = Tk()
    Window1 = BigWindow(root, "Word Problem Generator", "900x500")

Main()
```

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong or recommend a good learning resource?
Note the formatting is messsed up on pasting, but it is not an indentation issue as far as I can tell.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `e_add_minvar` is a local variable, `self.e_add_minvar` is an object attribute.

Comment: Thank you, this cleared it up. For anyone else struggling here, I needed to define e_add_minvar as self.e_add_minvar within the init and any other uses within init

Answer (score 1):

For the fix for those who may stumble on this post in need - It was a scope issue,  I had not defined the function e_add_minvar as self.e_add_minvar. Without the 'self.' it was treated as a local variable not an object.